# Intent Filters: How to create filter for all the Android versions (since the manufacters change it)

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to build an application that will serve contents to other applications.

**Take as an example**:

*Using the native Messaging app to attach an image from my provider.*

*In order to be a provider, I have registered some intent filters to do that. I use the ACTION_GET_CONTENT with image/* MIME types.*

[image: Example complete dialog]

I noticed that in some devices this works as expected, picking the application from the list in the "complete action using" dialog.

However, **some manufacturers, apparently seem to not comply with the Google "recommendations"**.

**How can we register for the ones that don't?**

I assume that some of them use implicit intent calls, is it possible to intercept also?

On the other side, if these intents are made explicitly, is it possible to "intercept" them and present the "complete action using" dialog?

Comment: In  my experience most of the time we have to live with those differences. If the OEMs mess something up there is not much we can do. Write the app with how it should work in mind and only make exceptions if a considerable part of your target audience has an "affected" device.

Answer (score 0):

1) If your question is "how to intercept intents with different (non standard names)" you can use the [intent intercept app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) to find out the required intent-settings.

2) if your question is "how to intercept activities which were not made for being intercepted" i am affraid you cannt.

i used the (1) approach to find out how to intercept googles-android-2.2-calendar-show-event that is officially not supported in version prior to 4.0 but works (at least on my handset).

i have the (2) issue with googles-android-4.4-calendar-show-event" which should be interceptable but is not. it is interceptable interceptable in versions prior to 4.4.

Comment: I have used that app to check the implicit intents but without any luck.
The complete action dialog is not shown and the target activity is open immediately.
Can I safely assume that in these cases the intent was called explicitly or implicitly with a custom settings (action, mime type, category, etc)?

Comment: if you mean "but without luck" that the `intent intercept` does not open up: i assume it is either not possible to intercept or the user has pressed the "always" button in the "complete action dialog". if i am wrong please correct me (and i can solve the issue (2) from my answer ).

Comment: yes, it does not open with the application that you pointed out. the defaults are not set as always. excluding possibilities, it seems that we are in these two possibilities: explicitly intent or implicitly intent with a custom settings. agree?